# regex match expression except specific string (no negative lookahead)

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

i'm trying to write a regex that matches most cases of HTML elements, like for example:

```
<script></script>
```

I would like to make an exception for the following HTML tag specifically:

```
<b>
```

Which I don't want to capture. Is there a way to do it without using negative lookahead/lookbehind?

At the moment i have something like this:

```
((\%3C)|<)[^<b]((\%2F)|\/)*[^<\/b][a-z0-9\%\=\'\(\)\ ]+((\%3E)|>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZxkVMJ/2

It does work, but beside

```
<b>
```

it also doesn't capture all 1 character tags

```
(like <a> for example)
```

as well as longer tags that start with b, like for example

```
<balloon>
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, if you have the availability of any kind of XML/HTML parser, you should really use that for your current problem.  If you are forced to use regex here, then consider this pattern:

```
<([^b][^>]*|b[^>]+)>.*?<\/\1>
```

This matches an HTML tag which either starts with a letter other than `b`, or a tag which does start with `b`, but then is followed by one or more other characters (thus ruling out `<b>`).  Here is a working demo:

### Demo